# Can I get an array of all the div ids that an item sits inside in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If I have some code that looks like this...

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
            <button type="button" name="button" id="clickme">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    var parents = //get an array of the ids that clickme is inside
});
</script>
```

Can I get an array of one,two,three in jQuery when the clickme button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The code I'm posting below works, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var array = [];
  $("#clickme").parents("*").each(function(){
    if(this.id != ''){
      array.push(this.id);
    }
  });
  console.log(array);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know until what level do you want to go. For example, if you want until body, you can do as below using [.parentsUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

```js
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    var parents = $(this).parentsUntil("body");
    parents.each(function(){console.log(this.id);});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
            <button type="button" name="button" id="clickme">Click Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you know you need to traverse till `#one`, you can do this:

```
 var parents = $(this).parentsUntil("#one");
```

Comment: Your right. In my case, I did want to know every single parent unit that had an I guess I could limit it to body for speed. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$('#clickme').on("click", function(){               
    var parents = $(this).parentsUntil("body");    
    var arrayOfIds = parents.map(function(index, item) { return item.id });  
        });
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/EM2cM/62/

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate your help.  This returns an object with a bunch of properties and each "id" it returns is actually the entire div, not the name of the div.   The one I posted below returns a simple array, it just doesn't look elegant to me.